# Error 403 when getting data from Airbnb API

Tags: python, api

I am trying to pull data from the Airbnb API, but I get a HTTP 403 error when running my code, this means I somehow don't have access to the Airbnb server. However, I do have an API key. Can someone please help me out here?

This is my code:

```
#Import required modules
import amadeus
import urllib2
import json

client_id= "**********"


#URL
URL = "https://api.airbnb.com/v2/search_results?  client_id=***********otqw18e8nh5nty&locale=en-US&currency=USD&_format=for_search_results_with_minimal_pricing&_limit=10&_offset=0&fetch_facets=true&guests=1&ib=false&ib_add_photo_flow=true&location=Lake%20Tahoe%2C%20CA%2C%20US&min_bathrooms=0&min_bedrooms=0&min_beds=1&min_num_pic_urls=10&price_max=210&price_min=40&sort=1&user_lat=37.3398634&user_lng=-122.0455164"
print URL

#Convert to Json format
json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(URL)

data = json.load(json_obj)

print data
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to send your apikey in request like this:

```
import urllib2
request = urllib2.Request("yourURL", headers={"X-Airbnb-OAuth-Token" : "yourapikey"})
contents = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

(im not 100% sure, but maybe it helps)

Comment: I tried your suggested code, however the same error was raised. It seems as if I do not have access to the server or something?

Comment: maybe you can try airbnb python api ( https://github.com/nderkach/airbnb-python )

Answer (score 0):

remove the spaces between '?' and 'client_id=...'

When I do that and then do a curl call, I get results.

And: **never** post your API-Key on sites like this.

Comment: I tried that, but it still gives me the same error. Can you elaborate on what you mean by a curl call?

Comment: I used the url to pass it as a string to the commandline `curl` tool, which just does a normal http get request, and I then got the results without further need to specifiy additional headers. So the url works. Does it work when copying and pasting the url in a browser?

Comment: It does work when copying the url into a browser. Sorry for the late reply. 
On my friends computer the same code does work however now.